# How to find the driver log when submit spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark

```
packages=(
'org.apache.spark:spark-core_1.11:2.2.0'
'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0'
'org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.2.0'
'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.43'
'org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-driver_2.11:2.1.0'
'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.4.2'
'com.github.scopt:scopt_2.11:3.7.0'
'com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:2.18.0'
'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:6.1.1'
'org.ansj:ansj_seg:5.1.5'
'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.2.0'
'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.2.0'
'com.sksamuel.elastic4s:elastic4s-core_2.11:6.1.4'
'com.sksamuel.elastic4s:elastic4s-http_2.11:6.1.4'
'com.softwaremill.sttp:core_2.11:1.1.9'
'com.softwaremill.sttp:core_2.11:1.1.9'
'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0'
'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
)

spark-submit --packages $(echo ${packages[*]} | tr ' ' ','}) --driver-class-path /data/bigdata/simple.jar --deploy-mode cluster --class com.xinpinget.bolt.stream.SCEventStreamTest --master spark://spark:7077 http://spark/tmp/all_2.11-0.1.jar
```

This is the script i use the submit spark job. The deploy mode is cluster. But after the job run, the driver log can't be find in spark ui and spark history. Only worker log can be found.

And under the `SPARK_HOME` directory, it can find driver log. But it's not very convenient to check the log in console every time.

Answer (score -1):

I founded it. The driver log is at the bottom of spark ui page.